# How do i make a frameless electron app movable while loading a local hosted url

Tags: node.js, electron

So currently i am building an electron application and have the backend written with python & flask so i am currently loading the local host url as seen below

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')




function createWindow () {
    var executablePath = 'app.exe';

var child = require('child_process').exec;
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    frame: false,
    transparent: true,
    movable: true,

    // show: false,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })


  mainWindow.loadURL('http://127.0.0.1:5001/')



}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
  
  app.on('activate', function () {

    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})


app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})
```

What i am confused about is how to make the application movable while still being frame less.

in other stack over flow reads i have been seeing to add this css.

```
.titlebar {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -webkit-app-region: drag;
}
```

My issue is where do i add this css if i am running the app its self from a local hosted URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
mainWindow.loadURL(`www.test.com`)
mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function() {
mainWindow.webContents.insertCSS('.titlebar{-webkit-user-select: none;-webkitapp-region: drag;}')`enter code here`
                });
```

refer for more https://discuss.atom.io/t/inject-css-to-loadurl/26845/6

Comment: Thanks for your help but this does not answer the question.

Comment: sorry try this one in this way you can add new css to your file

Comment: Thanks! perfect that fixed it